# What should be the VB.NET equivalent of below C# code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
//Insert new url in the image tag
src = "src=\"" + context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Url.Authority + src + "\"";
```

> Receiving Syntax error at "://" while converting from C# to to VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape sequence in `VB.NET` is by doubling the double-quotes.

```
src = "src=""" + context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Url.Authority + src + "\"""
```

Comment: It worked fine and I realised the cause. Although I had placed :// within double quotes however did not enclose    " + context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Url.Authority + src + "\"  in double quotes.

Comment: Actually the best is: `src = "src=""" & context.Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & context.Request.Url.Authority & src & "\"""`

Answer (score 3):

As @Olvarsham's answer puts, VB escapes double-quotes by doubling them.

However I feel it would be cleaner to rewrite the expression as a format-string:

```
src = String.Format("src=""{0}://{1}{2}""", context.Request.Url.Scheme, context.Request.Url.Authority, src)
```

If you reference `context.Request.Url` above, it gets simpler:

```
Dim url As Url = context.Request.Url
src = String.Format("src=""{0}://{1}{2}""", url.Scheme, url.Authority, src)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion using "Imports System.Security.Policy" however receiving error: Error 1 Value of type 'System.Uri' cannot be converted to 'System.Security.Policy.Url'. Please suggest

Comment: Just use implicit type: `Dim url = context.Request.Url`. By your import the compiler expects the shortened type `Url` to be of the fully qualified type `System.Security.Policy.Url` instead of the wanted `System.Uri`.

Comment: Works great. Wonderful suggestion!! Thank you